# ¿Como ocultar información de la Url en mi proyecto ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: html, mvc, asp.net-core

Tengo un proyecto en ASP.NET core MVC en donde utilizo diferentes vistas para mostrar unas tablas con información de base de datos, cuando ejecuto la app en mi navegador en la primera pantalla utilizo una validación como login en donde ingreso credenciales para poder ver las diferentes tablas con la información que les corresponde así como se ve en la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero despues de ingresar las credenciales me permite ver las diferentes tablas pero cuando ingreso a cualquiera y al revisar la Url del sitio me muestra información del usuario que no quiero que muestre cómo puedo hacer para ocultar esa información, ya lei varias preguntas similares en stackoverflow pero no logro entender las tecnologías que usan.
la Url se ve algo así: `https://localhost:7280/Home/Privacy?NumeroNIT=17527001`
y quisiera al menos ocultar la información que va despues del signo de interrogación `?`

Comment: No sabemos qué haces porque no hay código en la pregunta. Se asume por la URL que pasas datos entre páginas usando GET y ahí todo va en la URL. Entonces, lo sano con info sensible es conservarlos en el servidor, en los datos de sesión. Cuando tengas un ejemplo mínimo de tu código en la pregunta, puede que recibas respuestas concretas :)

Comment: buenas tardes @alfabravo muchas gracias por tu interes, la verdad es que no tengo claro en que parte del proyecto se le pasa la Url, no se que parte del código puedo mostrar para resolver mi duda por que soy principiante solamente cree el proyecto y cree las vistas pero nunca he visto algo referente a la Url que se muestra en el navegador